# SSRS 2019 with an oracle data source

Tags: ssrs, reporting, ssrs-2019

I am working on migrating a number of reports from an SSRS 2012 install to a SSRS 2019 install.  These are all pretty simple and straight forward reports, built in microsoft report builder.  A number of the reports use an oracle data source, these reports are giving me a heck of a time.  The following outlines the steps I have taken related to the oracle reports

1. I installed ssrs 2019, set it up per our team standards
2. Installed the oracle 19c administrator client
3. Installed the latest ODP.NET client (18.3)
4. Copied the tnsnames.ora file to both the admin client and the ODP.net client homes
5. Ensured the TNS_ADMIN environment variable was set
6. I made sure there was an entry in the rsreportserver.config file for oracle, which there is
7. Ensured I was able to resolve the oracle service name, by testing and making sure tnsping was able to resolve the name, and it was successful

I am still getting the following error, when trying to view the report from the ssrs server, or when trying to test the data source connection in the report builder.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
> An attempt has been made to use a data extension 'ORACLE' that is
> either not registered for this report server or is not supported in
> this edition of Reporting Services. (rsDataExtensionNotFound)

I have run through all the troubleshooting steps that I can think of, and I am not making any progress.

Comment: I've heard sometimes x86/x64 can be a headache. So folks usually install both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle client, just in case.  Did you try that?

Comment: Also, after installing, my server admin said he still had to run OraProvCfg.exe (in the ODP.NET bin 4 folder) for the GAC and machine.config